# Migrations File Error When Migrate Django Project

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project created by Django 1.x few years ago and I want migrate to Django 3.  When I test the updated project, it show errors in the migration files that the ForeignKey field missing the "on_delete" argument.  Since the "on_delete" argument is optional in Django 1 but mandatory in Django 3.  Is there any easy way to fix those errors?  Should I need to manually remove all "*.py" and "*.pyc" files in migrations directory of the app?  If I remove the files, will it affect the data in database and the migration processes in future?

Thanks,
Wilson

[image]

Comment: You need to update your models to conform with the standards in Django 3. Should be fairly easy to achieve if its just adding the `on_delete`.

Comment: Thank you for your advise!  I have update the models already but the error is from the migrations which I generated when running on Django 1.  I try to make new migrations after update the models but the execution was failed with some errors.

Comment: You should be fine to remove the migration files. Back them up just incase.